# Failing to trigger StreamingMultipleProgramsTestBase Test in Scala

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

according to

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/testing.html for Scala

Integration testing part

the test try looks pretty much the same

```
import java.util
import java.lang.Long
import com.google.common.collect.Lists
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.StreamingMultipleProgramsTestBase
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals



class HotelSearchIntegrationTest extends StreamingMultipleProgramsTestBase{

  @Test
  def testMatching(): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)


    env
      .fromElements(1L)
      .map( v => v).addSink( v => println(s"v"))

    // execute
    env.execute()

    assertEquals(1L, 1L)

  }

}
```

`sbt test`
brings me no executes tests back

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to         .../target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] Run completed in 10 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 7, 2018 4:30:45 PM
```

i just don't get what is wrong here.

thx for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while i figured it out.

there is another dependency that you need to put in your `build.sbt`

```
"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add this librarie as a dependencie to run your tests with scala http://www.scalatest.org

At least it's the librarie that i use to run my tests with Flink and everything works, but im using other syntax instead of JUnit